# How does the A-20 line overcome the Wrapping problem

Tags: assembly, x86, microprocessors

*When IBM designed the IBM PC AT machines, it used their newer Intel 80286 microprocessor, which was not entirely compatible with previous x86 microprocessors when in real mode. The problem? The older x86 processors did not have address lines A20 through A31. They did not have an address bus that size yet. Any programs that go beyond the first 1 MB would appear to wrap around. While it worked back then, the 80286's address space required 32 address lines. However, if all 32 lines are accessable, we get the wrapping problem again.*

The above is an excerpt from the following link on OS development :

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev9.html

I do have a doubt that I do not exactly understand what exactly is the wrapping problem but I guess it means something like an attempt to access an address greater than 1 MB would reach back to an address within 1 MB since , the higher bits of the address mean nothing owing to the presence of only 20 address lines from A0-A19 .

Is my guess correct ?

My second question is how does the A-20  line solve this problem ? 
I guess it when enabled somehow assigns  a meaning to the bits in the higher address lines but I do not know how to take this guess to a convincing answer .

So how does the A-20 line solve this problem ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the A-20 gate. It doesn't _solve_ the problem, it does the opposite, it disables address line 20 so older programs which used this fact that memory would wrap around kept working as they should.

Comment: @tkausl : Thanks a lot . But I feel I would need a bit more explanation regarding the state of affairs surrounding this .

Comment: @tkausl : maybe I do  not understand the wrapping problem itself in the first place .

Comment: Its the same concept as integers overflowing, only that it overflows at 20 bits.

Comment: This is related to CP/M `call 5` compatibility. Let me see if I can dig up an explanation.

Comment: Here is [some discussion](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/the-a20-gate-it-wasnt-wordstar/) about why the A20 gate was introduced.

Comment: Just a nit-pick, but the "1982 Introduction to the iAPX 286" says that the physical address bus is 24 bits, not 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the logical address `0xffff:0xffff`, its linear address is `0x10FFEF`.
If take a look at `0x10FFEF` in binary you'll see this:

```
B B    B    B    B    B  B 
i i    i    i    i    i  i
t t    t    t    t    t  t

2 1    1    1    0    0  0 
0 9    5    1    7    3  0
--------------------------
1 0000 1111 1111 1110 1111
```

As you see, it takes 21 bits (from bit 0 to bit 20) to represents this address.
`0xffff:0xffff` is a valid logical address so `0x10ffef` is a *valid* linear address.

This shows that 16-bit programs can generate 21-bit addresses.
But the 8086 and 80186 bus width was 20 bits.
What happens now?

What happens when you drive so many miles that your odometer reads 999,999.9?

[image: Rolling odometer]

It wraps around.
Mathematically we are just discarding the 7th digit so that 1,000,000.0 turns to 000,000.0.
This is the same with 21st bit - it is discarded and `0x10ffef` turns into `0x0ffef`.

Another good way to think about this is doing arithmetic on a hand clock: 7 + 7 = 14 = 2.
After the end it comes again the begin.
Another way to visualise this is to imagine the memory end has being glued to the beginning:

[image: Memory wrapped as a cylinder]

---

Now, some programs relied on this wrapping.
Not sure if this was a form of obfuscation of if this was used by the bios that had a segment already set to point around the end of the memory.

Whatever the reason was, when the 80286 expanded the memory bus to 24 bits this wrapping was eliminated.
It's like we'd add four more digits to our odometer, 1,000,000.0 is now representable without any problem.

To emulate the old 20-bit bus address, an external AND gate was added to force the bit20 to be zero.
This is like handwriting a 0 over the 7th digit of the odometer.

Problem solved.
This was an hack, only the bit 20 is set to zero, the higher bits are untouched.
This kinds of manipulations always generated repeating patterns, it's helping to spend a bit of time to draw them - especially to see how troublesome they can get if one forgets about enabling the a20.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by these higher bits ? The bits above 20 ?

Comment: After you have written  "If take a look at 0x10FFEF in binary you'll see this:
What exactly are these numbers  21 11 0 00 and 09 51 73 0  ?

Comment: @AmigorustBurrough Yes, bits above 20. The numbers are mean to be read vertically. I included the "Bit" word written top-down to hint it. It's hard to make figures with code blocks :/

Comment: I am really sorry but I need to understand how zeroing only the 20th bit solve the problem ? What is going on between those numbers , are they being added or multiplied or what ?

Comment: Sorry , I kind of understand the first one , i.e., only 20th bit zeroing but need to know the second one

Comment: Only the bit 20 is zeroed because the maximum linear address that can be generated in real-mode is 0x10ffef and this has no more than 21 bits. Please note that it is customary to number the bit starting from zero, so that bit 20 is 21st bit. The number above the bits are just labels, I numbered the bits so it would be easy to see that the last one (the left-most one) is bit20. This in turn means that such address *requires* 21 bits to be represented. You surely know that we can trim the non-significant digit from a number (0099 is 99) but we cannot trim non-zero digits.

Comment: To see how many bits a number requires we can simply look where the left-most one is (counting from the right of course). Since there is under the "Bit 20" (and thus that bit is the 21st one) label we know we need 21 bits for that address. And so we know it will lose that 21st bit when put in the address bus of an 80(1)86 because only 20-bit can fit in there. We also know that for a 80286 that number *won't* lose any bit because the address bus is now 24 bits wide. Finally, since `0xffff:0xffff` is the largest address we can have in real-mode, `0x10ffef` is the largest linear address...

Comment: ... and thus no more that 21 *significat* bits will ever be produced by a real-mode program. To make a 21-bit number looks like a 20-bit one, we only need to mask off the 21st bit. Note however, that when not in real-mode we can have linear addresses as large as 64-bit (currently only 57 bits) and if we forget to enable the a20 a repeating pattern of inaccessible memory arises.  This is like forcing the 2nd from the right digit of the odometer to zero, it will count 0-9, 0-9, 0-9, 0-9, 0-9, 0-9 0-9, 0-9, 0-9, 0-9, 100 - 109, 100 - 109, 100 - 109 and so one. I hope this helps.

Comment: I meant <<Since there is a 1 under the "Bit 20" (...) label>>. Some 's and article are missing, sorry. Comments are not very well suited for late editing.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Take a bow . I cannot express my gratitude . Thanks again